# Get map of map field from Firestore

Tags: node.js, typescript, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I have a field of type map that contains Maps of data in firestore.

[image]

I am trying to retrieve this data using a cloud function in node.js. I can get the document and the data from the field but i can't get it in a usable way. I have tried every solution i can find on SO and google but the below is the only code that can give me access to the data. I obviously need to be able to access each field with in the Map individually. in swift i build an array of String:Any but i can get that to work in Node.JS

```
const docRef = dbConst.collection('Comps').doc('XEVDk6e4AXZPkNprQRn5Imfcsah11598092006.724980');

return docRef.get().then(docSnap => {

 const tagets = docSnap.get('targets')

 console.log(tagets);

}).catch(result => { console.log(result) });
```

this is what i am getting back in the console.

[image]

In Swift i do the following and am so far not able to find an equivalent in typescript. (i don't need to build the custom object just ability to access the keys and values)

```
let obj1 = doc.get("targets") as! [String:Any]
                        
                        for objs in obj1{
                            let obs = objs.value as! [String:Any]
                            let targObj = compUserDetails(IDString: objs.key, activTarg: obs["ActivTarget"] as! Double, stepTarg: obs["StepTarget"] as! Double, name: obs["FullName"] as! String)
```

**UPDATE**
After spending a whole day working on it thought i had a solution using the below:

```
const docRef = dbConst.collection('Comps').doc('XEVDk6e4AXZPkNprQRn5Imfcsah11598092006.724980');

return docRef.get().then(docSnap => {
const tagets = docSnap.get('targets') as [[string, any]];
const newDataMap = [];

for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(tagets)) {
  const tempMap = new Map<String,any>();
  console.log(key);

  const newreWorked = value;

  tempMap.set('uid',key);

  for(let [key1, value1] of Object.entries(newreWorked)){
    tempMap.set(key1,value1);
    newDatMap.push(tempMap);
  };

};

  newDatMap.forEach(element => {
    const name = element.get('FullName');
    console.log(name);
  });
```

However the new data map has 6 seperate mapped objects. 3 of each of the original objects from the cloud. i can now iterate through and get the data for a given key but i have 3 times as many objects.

Comment: Have you read the documentation? https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/query-data/get-data

Comment: So you are getting random output in console each time you run it?

Comment: It looks like your log output doesn't match your code.  Each log line contains the string "testingProcess", but I don't see that anywhere in your code.  Anyway, there is certainly data in the object you're logging, and I think the output suggests to you how to access the fields of the object.  It's unclear to me where you're stuck simply accessing the properties of the objects you're logging.

Comment: @DougStevenson testingProcess is the name of the function.

Comment: @Gieted Yes every time i run it i get the log output in a different order and it never logs as one object always as multiple lines.

Comment: @ccarton yes i have read the docs and have no issues getting the data but cant get it into a usable format. If i try mapping keys and values or treating it as an array i get errors saying the snapshot can't be iterated

Comment: I have also tried console.log(Object.keys(tagets)); and all i get is numbers 0 through 27 instead of the actual keys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after two days of searching an getting very close i finnaly worked out a solution, it is very similar to the code above but this works. it may not be the "correct" way but it works. feel free to make other suggestions.

```
return docRef.get().then(docSnap => {
const tagets = docSnap.get('targets') as [[string, any]];
const newDatarray = [];

for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(tagets)) {
  const tempMap = new Map<String,any>();
  const newreWorked = value;
  tempMap.set('uid',key);

  for(let [key1, value1] of Object.entries(newreWorked)){
    tempMap.set(key1,value1);
  };
  newDatarray.push(tempMap);
};

  newDatarray.forEach(element => {
    const name = element.get('FullName');
    const steps = element.get('StepTarget');
    const avtiv = element.get('ActivTarget');
    const UID = element.get('uid');
    console.log(name);
    console.log(steps);
    console.log(avtiv);
    console.log(UID);
  });

 

}).catch(result => { console.log(result) });
```

Answer (score 0):

I made this into a little function that gets the underlying object from a map:

```js
function getMappedValues(map) {
    var tempMap = {};
    for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(map)) {
        tempMap[key] = value;
    }
    return tempMap;
}
```

For an object with an array of `map`s in firestore, you can get the value of the first of those maps like so:

```js
let doc = { // Example firestore document data
    items: {
        0: {
            id: "1",
            sr: "A",
        },
        1: {
            id: "2",
            sr: "B",
        },
        2: {
            id: "3",
            sr: "B",
        },
    },
};

console.log(getMappedValues(doc.items[0]));
```

which would read `{ id: '1', sr: 'A' }`