# Firebase Cloudfirestore get elements in a collections

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

Hello guys i'm trying to query a collection made in firebase cloudfirestore.

How can i create custom queries for objects inside an array.

This is how looks my collection:

```
"someRestaurantId": [{id:1,desc:"test",creationDate:"12/12/2020"},{id:2,desc:"test",creationDate:"12/12/2020"},{id:3,desc:"test",creationDate:"12/12/2020"}]
```

I have two problems how i can get only object for id:1 and then querie in a date range using creationDate input?

So far I been getting the full object based in the key: someRestaurantId, and then iterating in my nodejs function, but it could be many of restaurantsIds and many object and i don't want to kill the performance of the query if the object has thousands of results.

Comment: In order to investigate further, could you please describe if **someRestaurantId** is your "doc" or just the value like the following `{someRestaurantId: [{id:1,desc:"test",creationDate:"12/12/2020"},{id:2,desc:"test",creationDate:"12/12/2020"},{id:3,desc:"test",creationDate:"12/12/2020"}]}`. Could you please attach your Cloud Firestore Structure in order to visualize correctly?

Comment: @NibrassH someRestaurantId is a property for the objects inside the doc, it could be N amount of someRestaurantId into different "doc" / Collections

Comment: Please have a look into the [following similar post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63616856/8791788). Let me know if it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is now way to retrieve less than one document.